# Can I change pronunciation in Audacity?

Tags: audacity, voice-manipulation

I made 4 different character voices for my animation, only by manipulating my casual voice in Audacity, with RoVee plgin / effect, by changing the formant and the pitch of my voice in 4 different ways.  The result is OK, but the voices still seem quite similar, since the pronunciation is the same. Same L sounds, same  R sounds, same S sounds...

I cant seem to record different pronunciation...

Question:

Would the Autotune effect or some other plugin / effect help me to change the pronunciation?

I thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no. The voice is an extremely complex instrument - if you parameterize it there are more parameters to tweak than you can shake a stick at - formant and pitch are only two of many. My suggestion would be to do some background research on how the voice works - look up some articles on voice synthesis as well - this will give you a better idea as to what is involved.